# Warning when using https on my website

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm trying to secure my website with https. I managed to add the certificates and all that stuff but in some parts of the website i get this message "this website contains interactive content that isn't encrypted (such as scripts)". Any ideas on how to fixed this?

The website runs on localhost.
I am using Apache on OS X Mavericks

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have resources on your website (javascript for example) that isn't sent through a HTTPS request, but rather a regular HTTP request.

Try storing the resources on your own website instead of requesting them from a different one.

Answer (score 0):

yes. When you use https ALL pictures, SSC, and JS files should be loaded from your machine